# My html is not calling the JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me? I'm trying to call a JS file but is not working. I'm a newbie and really don't have any idea why.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stack</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <script>
      var fruits = new array();

      fruits[0] = "Apple";
      fruits[1] = "Strawberry";
      fruits[2] = "Orange";

      for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        document.write(fruits[i]+"</br>");
      }

      </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>JavaScript</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additionally to the other answers, use document.write inside the body and not in the head element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array instead of array

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Stack</title>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <script>
          var fruits = new Array();

          fruits[0] = "Apple";
          fruits[1] = "Strawberry";
          fruits[2] = "Orange";

          for(i=0; i<3; i++){
            document.write(fruits[i]+"</br>");
          }

          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>JavaScript</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Case sensitive boss

```
<script>
      var fruits = new Array();

      fruits[0] = "Apple";
      fruits[1] = "Strawberry";
      fruits[2] = "Orange";

      for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        document.write(fruits[i]+"</br>");
      }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

case sensitive:

```
<script>
              var fruits = new Array();

              fruits[0] = "Apple";
              fruits[1] = "Strawberry";
              fruits[2] = "Orange";

              for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                document.write(fruits[i]+"</br>");
              }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the array like this

```
var fruits = [];
```

Or do this

```
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Orange'];
```

Comment: Although in this case it solves the problem, this is not the answer to it, as it doesn't explain what the problem was (lowercase array, document.write in head etc.)